# Perimeter and area of hyperbolic octagon

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, polygons

How does one find the area and perimeter of the hyperbolic octagon with interior angles $\frac{\pi}2$? I'm completely stuck.

I have subdivided the octagon into eight hyperbolic triangles with two interior angles $\frac{\pi}4$. How can I now find the third angle?

Comment: Since you have done it, how do you  find area of a simpler hyperbolic triangle each angle $=\pi/6?$

Comment: Better divide your octagon  in 16 congruent  right angled triangles  the area is 16 times the area of the individual triangle and the perimeter is a bit of hyperbolic trigonometry

Comment: You write "**the** hyperbolic octagon with interior angles $\frac{\pi}{2}$" (my emphasis). But hyperbolic octagons with those interior angles are not unique up to congruence. Indeed, they may have arbitrarily large perimeter.

Comment: @Willemien Do you mean that if I subdivide it into 16 triangles, it will be easier to find the third angle? Will the second angle be $\frac{\pi}2$, the first one will be $\frac{\pi}4$, but how does this help?

Comment: @Narasimham It will be $\pi - \frac{\pi}2=\frac{\pi}2$. But I'm not sure how this would help, since I don't see how the octagon could be subdivided into such triangles.

Comment: There are 8 equilateral triangles. Each vertex has half angle $\pi/4$ and if Gauss curvature is $-1/a^2,$ then each triangle has pseudospherical deficit $ \pi- 3 \pi/4 = \pi/4.$ For the full octagon area $= a^2 8\, \pi/4 = 2\pi a^2.$

Comment: @Narasimham Can you please clarify what is your $a$? We didn't cover Gaussian curvature.

Comment: It is radius of cuspidal equator of pseudo-spheres. Do you know pseudospherical deficit? GB thm?

Comment: We didn't cover that... I believe the idea is to use some less advanced methods.

Comment: Sorry has nothing to do with the third angle (which is pi/8 ) but with calculating the ( external) side length because it is now a right angled triangles (angles pi/2 = right, pi/4 and pi/8) and thus cosh s = cos(pi/8) / sin(pi/4) and your perimeter is 16 s see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_triangle > trigonometry

Comment: @Willemien Do you mean that the sum of the angles in a right hyperbolic triangle does not depend on the size of the triangle?

Comment: No I even show how to calculate one of the side lengths given the 3 angles (the formulas for all sides are more or less given , be aware they are only true if the curvature is -1 and cosh is an hyperbolic function) is is just the formulas for triangles with a right angle are easier :)

Comment: @Willemien But how did you get the 3rd angle? Of course I could calculate the side lengths if I had the third angle. But I only have two angles.

Comment: All the third angles meet in one point the centre of the octagon , are all the same size , do not overlap ect so they are 2pi divided by the number of triangles

Comment: @Willemien thanks, I didn't know if that fact applied to hyperbolic geometry.

Comment: @Willemien How did you get perimeter 16? $\cosh(s)=\frac{\cos(\pi/8)}{\sin(\pi/4)}$, so that $s=\cosh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\right)$.

Comment: I mend 16 times s ( with s being the side of one triangle ) I haven't checked your value of s yet (will do tomorrow)

Comment: @sequence  may be better to study Poincare metric later on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine we have your octagon we divide it in 8 equal sectors, (all meeting at the centre of the octagon) then every sector has a top angle at the centre  of $ \frac {2 \pi} {8} = \frac {\pi} {4} $  and base angles are the internal angle / 2 $ = \frac {\pi  / 2} {2} = \frac {\pi} {4} $

We have 8 of these sectortriangles.

(Only while writing this realised it were all equilateral triangles, but for being more general and following the reasoning in the comments, we just overlook this)

For trigonomic reasons we cut all sectortriangles in half from the top angle to the middle of the base

so we now have 16 triangles each having angles of

- half internal angle $ (= \frac {\pi} {4} )$
- half top angle of sectortriangles $ (= \frac {\pi} {4 * 2} = \frac {\pi} {8} ) $
- right angle $ (=\frac {\pi} {2} )$

The area of this triangle is 
$ (\pi- \frac {\pi} {4} - \frac {\pi} {8} - \frac { \pi} {2} = \frac {\pi} {8} $

Following wikipedia.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_triangle#Relations_between_angles

$ \cos A = \cosh a \sin B $

$ \sin A = \frac{\cos B}{\cosh b} $

$ \tan A = \frac{\cot B}{\cosh c} $

Or rewritten

$ \cosh a = \frac{ \cos A} { \sin B} $

$ \cosh b = \frac{ \cos B} { \sin A } $

$ \cosh c = \frac{ \cot B} { \tan A} $

filled in

$ \cosh a = \frac{\cos \frac{\pi} {4}} {\sin \frac{\pi} {8}} $

$ \cosh b = \frac{\cos \frac {\pi} {8}} {\sin \frac{\pi} {4} } $

$ \cosh c = \frac{\cot \frac {\pi} {8}} {\tan \frac {\pi} {4}} $

caculated (not exact values)

$ \cosh a = 1.848 \to a = 1.224  $

$ \cosh b = 1.307 \to b = 0.764  $

$ \cosh c = 2.414 \to c = 1.529  $

Now we have all there is to say about  a regular octagon with internal right angles:

the area is $ 16 * \frac {\pi} {8} = 2{\pi}$

the perimater is $ 16 * 0.764 = 12.229 $

the radius of the inscribed circle is $ 1.224$

the radius of the circumscribed circle is $  1.529 $

Thats all :)